# esint package leads to misprinted integrals

Tags: fonts, printing

If I print a document using the package `esint` and the `mathpazo` font the integral signs (`\int`, `\iint`) are all cut at the bottom. I tested different printers with both a Linux and Mac system and got the same result. Everything is fine if I remove the `esint` package.
Is there a chance to remove this problem or is there a package that produces similar output to `\iint` with `esint`?

Minimal example that reproduces the problem for me:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
\[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \]
\end{document}
```

And a more evolved example

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\frenchspacing

\usepackage{esint}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is working for me (means no cut). Looks like it is time for an upgrade for packages.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Windows with TeX Live 2011. I expect the example can be minimized a bit further, too--what other packages can you remove and still show the problem on your test systems? For example, if removing `amsthm` and `scrpage2` still shows the error, we know the problem is either a bug in your version of `esint`, or only shows up as an interaction between `esint` and another package or group of packages.

Comment: I also noticed that the `intlimits` option of `amsmath` does not work with `esint`. Another argument to look for a replacement…

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a comment with a picture. Your code  works fine  for me. Just to show:

[image]

**It seems you may have to upgrade your packages.**

Comment: If this would be a scan of a printed integral I would believe you. There is no problem visible at the screen at all. Only printing gives the misprinted integral.

Comment: Then some thing is wrong with your printer. Have you tried different printers?

Comment: I printed it to a file and it is fine again. FYI I use MikTeX 2.9 on windows. I do not know understand:)

Comment: I also could not reproduce the error on viewing or printing (with Adobe Reader 9.5) and TeX Live 2011 on Windows.

Comment: I'm using TexLive 2011 too but I don't have a windows system available. I posted a real minimal example that works to. As already stated the problem also occurs on different printers. But I only tested with Laser printers via printserver and direct printing.